# how to get total working time using php

Tags: php

I have to find the total working time of a staff.

Variables in my hand is,

```
$work_time_start = "8:00:00";
$work_time_end = "18:00:00";
$lunch_break_start = "13:00:00";
$lunch_break_end = "14:00:00";
```

From this I have to find the total working time of a staff.

For example.

```
//example 1    

$work_start_time = "14:00:00";
$work_end_time = "14:25:00";

//The output should be: 00:25:00

//example 2

$work_start_time = "14:00:00";
$work_end_time = "10:25:00";

//The output should be: 06:25:00
```

How to achieve the required output. I have no idea.

Comment: convert everything to plain seconds, then work with it and convert back for display as necesary.

Comment: This is basically getting the time difference with some special cases. It's not an exact duplicate but you should be able to work out an answer based on the many many other similar questions out there. At least show us what you tried.

Comment: Why should output of example 2 be 06:25:00?  Are you working in a mixture of 24 and 12 hour time formats without defining which is which? Don't expect any answer here to work if that's the case. You need to normalize your data. It's impossible to work with

Answer (score 1):

Detailed answer as requested.

```
$work_time_start = "8:00:00";
$work_time_end = "18:00:00";
$lunch_break_start = "13:00:00";
$lunch_break_end = "14:00:00";

$worktime = convert_to_seconds($work_time_end) - convert_to_seconds($work_time_start);

$lunchtime = convert_to_seconds($lunch_break_end) - convert_to_seconds($lunch_break_start);

$worktime = $worktime - $lunchtime;
echo $worktime;


function convert_to_seconds($str_time)
{

    $str_time = preg_replace("/^([\d]{1,2})\:([\d]{2})$/", "00:$1:$2", $str_time);

    sscanf($str_time, "%d:%d:%d", $hours, $minutes, $seconds);

    $time_seconds = $hours * 3600 + $minutes * 60 + $seconds;

    return $time_seconds;
}
```

Comment: what about `$work_start_time` and `$work_end_time`

Answer (score -1):

Hope this helps

```
$work_start_time =new DateTime("14:00:00");
$work_end_time = new DateTime("14:25:00");
$interval = $work_end_time->diff($work_start_time);

echo $interval->format('%H:%I:%S');
```

Answer (score -1):

Use the following code:

```
$work_time_start = "8:00:00";
$work_time_end = "18:00:00";
$lunch_break_start = "13:00:00";
$lunch_break_end = "14:00:00";
$total_time = strtotime($lunch_break_start) - strtotime($work_time_start) + strtotime($work_time_end) - strtotime($lunch_break_end);
echo date("h:i:s", mktime(0,0, round($total_time) % (24*3600)));
```